# Terraform creating role with missing AccessKeyId

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

Terraform is creating role and attaching it to the EC2 instance successfully.
However, when I try to run commands with `aws cli`, it is giving error with `missing AccessKeyId`:

`aws ec2 describe-instances --debug`

```
2022-01-12 18:44:25,755 - MainThread - botocore.utils - DEBUG - Retrieved credentials is missing required field: AccessKeyId
2022-01-12 18:44:25,755 - MainThread - botocore.utils - DEBUG - Error response received when retrievingcredentials: {'Code': 'AssumeRoleUnauthorizedAccess', 'Message': 'EC2 cannot assume the role tf_eks_role_bastion.  Please see documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/troubleshoot_iam-ec2.html#troubleshoot_iam-ec2_errors-info-doc.', 'LastUpdated': '2022-01-12T18:42:15Z'}.
```

My `main.tf` creates a role, attaches two policies to it, creates an instance-profile for the role and attaches the instance-profile to the newly created ec2-instance.

I got it working while changing `main.tf` and constanly re-applying the changes. But after executing `terraform destroy` and then `terraform apply` again, it stopped working again.

Also, when I create a role in AWS Console manually and attach it to the same ec2-instance, it starts working.

Does anyone understand this `missing AccessKeyId` error?

My `main.tf`:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.27"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 0.14.9"
}

provider "aws" {
  profile = "default"
  region  = "eu-central-1"
}

resource "aws_security_group" "http_sg" {
  name = "tf_bastion_host allow ht_p inbound from anywhere"
  ingress {
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "ssh_sg" {
  name = "tf_bastion_host allow ssh from anywhere"
  ingress {
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

# create role for bastion host
resource "aws_iam_role" "eks_role" {
  name = "tf_eks_role_bastion"

  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    "Statement" : [
      {
        "Effect" : "Allow",
        "Principal" : {
          "Service" : "eks.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action" : "sts:AssumeRole"
      },
    ]
  })

  tags = {
    tag-key = "tf_bastion_host"
  }
}

# attach policy to role
resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "eks_attachment_cluster_policy" {
  name       = "tf_eks_attachment_cluster_policy"
  roles      = ["${aws_iam_role.eks_role.name}"]
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSClusterPolicy"
}

# attach policy to role
resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "eks_attachment_service_policy" {
  name       = "tf_eks_attachment_service_policy"
  roles      = ["${aws_iam_role.eks_role.name}"]
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSServicePolicy"
}

# create an instance profile
resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "bastion_host_profile" {
  name = "tf_bastion_host_profile"
  role = aws_iam_role.eks_role.name
}

resource "aws_instance" "bastion_host" {
  ami                         = "ami-05d34d340fb1d89e5"
  instance_type               = "t2.micro"
  count                       = 1
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  # use the jenkins key-pair for now
  key_name = "jenkins"

  # attach the instance profile to the EC2 instance
  iam_instance_profile = aws_iam_instance_profile.bastion_host_profile.name

  vpc_security_group_ids = [
    aws_security_group.http_sg.id,
    aws_security_group.ssh_sg.id
  ]

  user_data = file("installs.sh")

  tags = {
    Name        = "tf_bastion_host",
    Environment = "production"
  }
}
```

Output of `terraform apply -auto-approve`:

```
Terraform used the selected providers to generate the
following execution plan. Resource actions are
indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_iam_instance_profile.bastion_host_profile will be created
  + resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "bastion_host_profile" {
      + arn         = (known after apply)
      + create_date = (known after apply)
      + id          = (known after apply)
      + name        = "tf_bastion_host_profile"
      + path        = "/"
      + role        = "tf_eks_role_bastion"
      + tags_all    = (known after apply)
      + unique_id   = (known after apply)
    }

  # aws_iam_policy_attachment.eks_attachment_cluster_policy will be created
  + resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "eks_attachment_cluster_policy" {
      + id         = (known after apply)
      + name       = "tf_eks_attachment_cluster_policy"
      + policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSClusterPolicy"
      + roles      = [
          + "tf_eks_role_bastion",
        ]
    }

  # aws_iam_policy_attachment.eks_attachment_service_policy will be created
  + resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "eks_attachment_service_policy" {
      + id         = (known after apply)
      + name       = "tf_eks_attachment_service_policy"
      + policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSServicePolicy"
      + roles      = [
          + "tf_eks_role_bastion",
        ]
    }

  # aws_iam_role.eks_role will be created
  + resource "aws_iam_role" "eks_role" {
      + arn                   = (known after apply)
      + assume_role_policy    = jsonencode(
            {
              + Statement = [
                  + {
                      + Action    = "sts:AssumeRole"
                      + Effect    = "Allow"
                      + Principal = {
                          + Service = "eks.amazonaws.com"
                        }
                    },
                ]
              + Version   = "2012-10-17"
            }
        )
      + create_date           = (known after apply)
      + force_detach_policies = false
      + id                    = (known after apply)
      + managed_policy_arns   = (known after apply)
      + max_session_duration  = 3600
      + name                  = "tf_eks_role_bastion"
      + name_prefix           = (known after apply)
      + path                  = "/"
      + tags                  = {
          + "tag-key" = "tf_bastion_host"
        }
      + tags_all              = {
          + "tag-key" = "tf_bastion_host"
        }
      + unique_id             = (known after apply)

      + inline_policy {
          + name   = (known after apply)
          + policy = (known after apply)
        }
    }

  # aws_instance.bastion_host[0] will be created
  + resource "aws_instance" "bastion_host" {
      + ami                                  = "ami-05d34d340fb1d89e5"
      + arn                                  = (known after apply)
      + associate_public_ip_address          = true
      + availability_zone                    = (known after apply)
      + cpu_core_count                       = (known after apply)
      + cpu_threads_per_core                 = (known after apply)
      + disable_api_termination              = (known after apply)
      + ebs_optimized                        = (known after apply)
      + get_password_data                    = false
      + host_id                              = (known after apply)
      + iam_instance_profile                 = "tf_bastion_host_profile"
      + id                                   = (known after apply)
      + instance_initiated_shutdown_behavior = (known after apply)
      + instance_state                       = (known after apply)
      + instance_type                        = "t2.micro"
      + ipv6_address_count                   = (known after apply)
      + ipv6_addresses                       = (known after apply)
      + key_name                             = "jenkins"
      + monitoring                           = (known after apply)
      + outpost_arn                          = (known after apply)
      + password_data                        = (known after apply)
      + placement_group                      = (known after apply)
      + placement_partition_number           = (known after apply)
      + primary_network_interface_id         = (known after apply)
      + private_dns                          = (known after apply)
      + private_ip                           = (known after apply)
      + public_dns                           = (known after apply)
      + public_ip                            = (known after apply)
      + secondary_private_ips                = (known after apply)
      + security_groups                      = (known after apply)
      + source_dest_check                    = true
      + subnet_id                            = (known after apply)
      + tags                                 = {
          + "Environment" = "production"
          + "Name"        = "tf_bastion_host"
        }
      + tags_all                             = {
          + "Environment" = "production"
          + "Name"        = "tf_bastion_host"
        }
      + tenancy                              = (known after apply)
      + user_data                            = "f27e2f754e7658f0f0cdd09facb579d44b20ea5f"
      + user_data_base64                     = (known after apply)
      + vpc_security_group_ids               = (known after apply)

      + capacity_reservation_specification {
          + capacity_reservation_preference = (known after apply)

          + capacity_reservation_target {
              + capacity_reservation_id = (known after apply)
            }
        }

      + ebs_block_device {
          + delete_on_termination = (known after apply)
          + device_name           = (known after apply)
          + encrypted             = (known after apply)
          + iops                  = (known after apply)
          + kms_key_id            = (known after apply)
          + snapshot_id           = (known after apply)
          + tags                  = (known after apply)
          + throughput            = (known after apply)
          + volume_id             = (known after apply)
          + volume_size           = (known after apply)
          + volume_type           = (known after apply)
        }

      + enclave_options {
          + enabled = (known after apply)
        }

      + ephemeral_block_device {
          + device_name  = (known after apply)
          + no_device    = (known after apply)
          + virtual_name = (known after apply)
        }

      + metadata_options {
          + http_endpoint               = (known after apply)
          + http_put_response_hop_limit = (known after apply)
          + http_tokens                 = (known after apply)
        }

      + network_interface {
          + delete_on_termination = (known after apply)
          + device_index          = (known after apply)
          + network_interface_id  = (known after apply)
        }

      + root_block_device {
          + delete_on_termination = (known after apply)
          + device_name           = (known after apply)
          + encrypted             = (known after apply)
          + iops                  = (known after apply)
          + kms_key_id            = (known after apply)
          + tags                  = (known after apply)
          + throughput            = (known after apply)
          + volume_id             = (known after apply)
          + volume_size           = (known after apply)
          + volume_type           = (known after apply)
        }
    }

  # aws_security_group.http_sg will be created
  + resource "aws_security_group" "http_sg" {
      + arn                    = (known after apply)
      + description            = "Managed by Terraform"
      + egress                 = [
          + {
              + cidr_blocks      = [
                  + "0.0.0.0/0",
                ]
              + description      = ""
              + from_port        = 0
              + ipv6_cidr_blocks = []
              + prefix_list_ids  = []
              + protocol         = "-1"
              + security_groups  = []
              + self             = false
              + to_port          = 0
            },
        ]
      + id                     = (known after apply)
      + ingress                = [
          + {
              + cidr_blocks      = [
                  + "0.0.0.0/0",
                ]
              + description      = ""
              + from_port        = 80
              + ipv6_cidr_blocks = []
              + prefix_list_ids  = []
              + protocol         = "tcp"
              + security_groups  = []
              + self             = false
              + to_port          = 80
            },
        ]
      + name                   = "tf_bastion_host allow ht_p inbound from anywhere"
      + name_prefix            = (known after apply)
      + owner_id               = (known after apply)
      + revoke_rules_on_delete = false
      + tags_all               = (known after apply)
      + vpc_id                 = (known after apply)
    }

  # aws_security_group.ssh_sg will be created
  + resource "aws_security_group" "ssh_sg" {
      + arn                    = (known after apply)
      + description            = "Managed by Terraform"
      + egress                 = [
          + {
              + cidr_blocks      = [
                  + "0.0.0.0/0",
                ]
              + description      = ""
              + from_port        = 0
              + ipv6_cidr_blocks = []
              + prefix_list_ids  = []
              + protocol         = "-1"
              + security_groups  = []
              + self             = false
              + to_port          = 0
            },
        ]
      + id                     = (known after apply)
      + ingress                = [
          + {
              + cidr_blocks      = [
                  + "0.0.0.0/0",
                ]
              + description      = ""
              + from_port        = 22
              + ipv6_cidr_blocks = []
              + prefix_list_ids  = []
              + protocol         = "tcp"
              + security_groups  = []
              + self             = false
              + to_port          = 22
            },
        ]
      + name                   = "tf_bastion_host allow ssh from anywhere"
      + name_prefix            = (known after apply)
      + owner_id               = (known after apply)
      + revoke_rules_on_delete = false
      + tags_all               = (known after apply)
      + vpc_id                 = (known after apply)
    }

Plan: 7 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Changes to Outputs:
  + private_instance_ip = (known after apply)
  + public_instance_dns = (known after apply)
aws_iam_role.eks_role: Creating...
aws_security_group.http_sg: Creating...
aws_security_group.ssh_sg: Creating...
aws_security_group.http_sg: Creation complete after 3s [id=sg-0ae7e9865c60ce9c9]
aws_security_group.ssh_sg: Creation complete after 3s [id=sg-016f588fb10a7dbad]
aws_iam_role.eks_role: Creation complete after 3s [id=tf_eks_role_bastion]
aws_iam_policy_attachment.eks_attachment_cluster_policy: Creating...
aws_iam_policy_attachment.eks_attachment_service_policy: Creating...
aws_iam_instance_profile.bastion_host_profile: Creating...
aws_iam_policy_attachment.eks_attachment_service_policy: Creation complete after 2s [id=tf_eks_attachment_service_policy]
aws_iam_instance_profile.bastion_host_profile: Creation complete after 2s [id=tf_bastion_host_profile]
aws_instance.bastion_host[0]: Creating...
aws_iam_policy_attachment.eks_attachment_cluster_policy: Creation complete after 2s [id=tf_eks_attachment_cluster_policy]
aws_instance.bastion_host[0]: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
aws_instance.bastion_host[0]: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
aws_instance.bastion_host[0]: Still creating... [30s elapsed]
aws_instance.bastion_host[0]: Creation complete after 39s [id=i-07926ae9044680939]

Apply complete! Resources: 7 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the assume_role_policy of your IAM role

```
          "Service" : "eks.amazonaws.com"
```

should be changed to

```
          "Service" : "ec2.amazonaws.com"
```

If your role is going to be used by an EC2 instance, the allowed principal needs to be `ec2.amazonaws.com`. You might also want to review the managed policies you are attaching to the role, they are more suitable for an EKS cluster and not a bastion host.

Comment: That solved the issue. Thank you so much, it took me so much time to analyse. I want to use the bastion host to create and manage EKS cluster, hence managed policies are what I am looking for. Thank you for the note, though.